# Adding custom jobs to Laravel

Tags: laravel, command

I have a few users in a Laravel application.

Each user sets a time (hour and minute) saved in the database to send emails.

What I already do:

I have a command that is executed every minute:

```
$schedule->command(check_emails)->everyMinute();
```

If an user is set to send their emails at that time, it will be sent.

Is there a way to set the command automaticly to send emails at the time that the users have set instead of needing to check it every minute from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments with your commands. Set signature of the console command as given below.

```
protected $signature = 'check_emails {time}';
```

Here time is the argument pass to your console command. It can be minute or hour that the value stored in database.

```
$schedule->command('check_emails minute')->everyMinute();
$schedule->command('check_emails hour')->hourly();
```

This two schedules will help you to find the users who have prefered hourly emails and emails in  every minutes. So your code can make condition to find out for a users separately. Since you are taking the advantage of arguments you no needs to create two functions.

In your console command handle codes may look this.

```
$time = $this->argument('time');
// Get the users who set send_email_time at $time
$users = User::where('send_email_time', $time)->get();
// ...
// Code to send email to $users
// ...
```